# Single JSON argument in mutation

Tags: json, graphql, graphql-js

Below I'm trying to set a mutation `example` with one object-arg `credentials`. I had this working previously then all the sudden it stopped working failing on the JSON part. Why can't I send json through `credentials`?

```
import {
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLInputObjectType,
  GraphQLNonNull,
  graphql
} from 'graphql'


let requestType = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'Request',
  fields: {
    name: {type: GraphQLString},
  }
})

let responseType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Response',
  fields: {
    name: {type: GraphQLString},
    age: {type: GraphQLInt}
  }
})

let schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query:  new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
      author: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve: (source, args, context, info) => {
          return 'Thomas Reggi'
        }
      }
    }
  }),
  mutation: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
      example: {
        type: responseType,
        args: {
          credentials: {
            name: 'credentials',
            type: requestType
          }
        },
        resolve: (source, args, context, info) => {
          return {
            'name': 'Thomas Reggi',
            'age': 26
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
})

let credentials = { name: "Thomas Reggi" }

let requestString = `
mutation {
  example(credentials: ${JSON.stringify(credentials)}) {
    name,
    age
  }
}`

graphql(schema, requestString).then(result => {
  console.log(result)
})
```

Here's the error:

```
{ errors: 
   [ Syntax Error GraphQL request (3:25) Expected Name, found String "name: "

     2: mutation {
     3:   example(credentials: {"name":"Thomas Reggi"}) {
                                ^
     4:     name,
      ] }
```

Where does the reference to `Name` come from? Why is this throwing an error?

Comment: FYI, in your `requestString`, you didn't have properly quoted string here: `example(credentials: {"name: "Thomas Reggi"})`

Comment: I had a typo, but I still can't get JSON to work, where the keys are in quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found out the hard way. You can't have `{"name": "Thomas Reggi"}` because name is in quotes.

This query works.

```
mutation {
  example(credentials: {name: "Thomas Reggi"}) {
    name,
    age
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking at Apollo GraphQL client code and mutations with complex parameters are a real pain. I think stringifying the JSON, and then remove  quotes on field names would work.

Comment: Thanks! Wasted hours on this. You know any good tool to remove those double quotes for the keys only? (why another format? ><)

Comment: For anyone else looking, this is a good and simple solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3651373/2391795